# Errors running UI Test after EarlGrey Installation

Tags: earlgrey

I'm currently unable to build my UITests after completing the EarlGrey 2 installation steps.

I get the following:

/Users/morgan/Documents/WineSpectator/git/WineRatingsPlus/EarlGrey/CommonLib/DistantObject/GREYHostApplicationDistantObject.h:23:9: 'EDOClientService.h' file not found

I'm guessing that my `User Header Search Paths` may be incorrect. It seems like they're finding EarlGrey references, but not eDO references.

Currently these are set to:

./EarlGrey
./Submodules/eDistantObject

based on the setup instructions here:

https://github.com/google/EarlGrey/blob/earlgrey2/docs/setup.md

> Blockquote Add the User Header Search Paths for the EarlGrey directory (the directory containing the EarlGrey.xcodeproj) and the eDistantObject directory (the directory containing the eDistantObject.xcodeproj) so all the headers can be accessed.

Does anybody have any advise, or a working set of User Header Search Paths - granted this may not be the actual issue.

Comment: Did you add the Submodules/ directory in header search paths as well?

Comment: They were set to:

/EarlGrey
./Submodules/eDistantObject

tried adding:

/Submodule

then


./Submodule

tried recursive and non-recursive.

Same error.